# Capturing toast message and pop outs in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, toast

I want to capture text in toast messages and pop-out like "user registered successfully, user already exist" for assertion in Selenium using Python.
I used the following code to get the text but it didn't helped me.

```
    popup = driver.switch_to.alert()
    assert "User already exist" in popup.text
    popup.accept()
```

Comment: toast message popup may not be a javascript popup. It may be just application popup. you can use normal find element.

Comment: Toast will a html element only. Also if it is a disappearing one then it might be tough for you, as you need to time your find element before the element disappears

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get text generated by JS in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339605/how-to-get-text-generated-by-js-in-selenium)

Answer (score 2):

Toast messages are not window alert that you can switch to. They have html tags that shows up briefly in the DOM. You basically need to:

1. Click on the button that fires them
2. Right click on the toast-message and click inspect element
3. Keep the mouse on the the toast message, that way the toast message don't fade away
4. Look at the properties of the toast message in the developer tools triggered in step 2 and decide which element locator you want to use
   to locate the toast message
5. Make sure you use an explicit wait right after clicking the action that should fire the toast message, that way your script wait for it
   to show up.